# How to guess the particular solution form from forcing function?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, switches, inductor, transient

$$2\frac{dv(t)}{dt}+v(t)=5t\sin(t)$$

According to the general equation for first-order differential circuits, \$5t\sin(t)\$ is my forcing function. My task here is to find the particular solution.

I was told to guess the particular solution form and then solve the unknowns (A, B, C, and D.)

A hint was given which said "The particular solution includes terms with the same functional forms as the terms found in forcing function and its derivatives."

Why is the particular solution \$v_p(t) = \small At\sin(t) + Bt \sin(t) + C \sin(t) + D \cos(t)\$?

Why is it not \$v_p(t) = \small A \sin(t) + B \cos (t)\$?

I am finding it really difficult to guess the forms just from the hint.

Any explanation or a proper YouTube video or any link where this is properly explained will be really appreciated.

Comment: Ain't no such thing as a "proper YouTube video."

Comment: @JRE Sorry, wrong adjective used. I meant to say helpful or a Youtube video with clear explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the little \$t\$ that sits in front of the sine function there. First set up the equation in standard form:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} v_t+\frac12 v_t=2.5 t\sin t$$

This can also be expressed a little more elegantly as:

$$\left[D +\frac12\right] v_t=2.5 t\sin t$$

The [denominator of the Laplace transform of the right side](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=laplace+transform+5*t*sin%28t%29&key=p6xrc) is \$\left(s^2+1\right)^2\$. So \$\left[\left(D^2+1\right)^2\right]\$ will annihilate the right expression. The fact that this is squared means that terms for the first power of \$t\$ must be included in the solution.

Here's proof of that:

$$\begin{align*}
\left[\left(D^2+1\right)^2\right]2.5 t\sin t
\\
\left[D^2+1\right]\left[D^2+1\right]2.5 t\sin t
\\
\left[D^2+1\right]\left[\vphantom{D^2+1}\left(-2.5 t\sin t+5\cos t\right)+2.5 t\sin t\right]
\\
\left[D^2+1\right]5\cos t
\\
\left[\left(-5\cos t\right)+5\cos t\right]
\\
0
\end{align*}$$

Note that it took two of the \$\left[D^2+1\right]\$ to kill both the \$t\$ and also the \$\sin t\$. That's why it had to be squared. If there was a \$t^2\$ in front, a third power would have been required, instead. Etc.

So the original equation becomes:

$$\begin{align*}\left[D +\frac12\right] v_t&=2.5 t\sin t\\\\
\left[D^2+1\vphantom{\frac12}\right]^2\left[D +\frac12\right] v_t&=\left[D^2+1\vphantom{\frac12}\right]^22.5 t\sin t\\\\\left[D^2+1\vphantom{\frac12}\right]^2\left[D +\frac12\right] v_t&=0\end{align*}$$

That's homogeneous and will have the general solution form of:

$$v_t=A_1\exp\left(-\frac12 t\right)+A_2 t\cos t+A_3 t\sin t+A_4\cos t+A_5\sin t$$

The first term (the exponential) provides the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation and the last four constitute a particular solution to the non-homogeneous part, with undetermined coefficients.

Direct substitution results in:

$$\begin{align*}\left[D+\frac12\right]v_t&=\left(\frac12A_2+A_3\right)t\cos t\\&+\left(-A_2+\frac12 A_3\right)t\sin t\\&+\left(A_2+\frac12 A_4+A_5\right)\cos t\\&+\left(A_3-A_4+\frac12 A_5\right)\sin t\\&=2.5 t\sin t\end{align*}$$

The undetermined coefficients can now be worked out simultaneously to yield:

$$v_t=A_1\exp\left(-\frac12 t\right)-2 t\cos t+ t\sin t+\frac85\cos t+\frac65\sin t$$

Plug that back into the standard form shown at the outset above and find that the equation now balances.

See Section 6.3, *"Undetermined Coefficients and the Annihilator Method"* from the 9th edition of *"Fundamentals of Differential Equations"* by Nagle, Saff, and Snider, Pearson 2018

Comment: I understood a lot of it, but I am just in my first semester and I am not familiar with Laplace transformation yet. But I will look it up. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RKEshat Just remember two things. If anything of the form \$\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right]^m\$ then the general solution includes \$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} A_k\,t^k\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\$ and if anything of the form \$\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\right]^m\$ then the general solution includes \$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} A_{2k}\,t^k\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\cos\left(\beta\,t\right) + A_{2k+1}\,t^k\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)\$. You don't need to know anything else. That covers almost all ills. I mentioned Laplace only in case you see something new.

Comment: @RKEshat Laplace is usually taught ***after*** annihilators are taught. Not before. So you really don't need to know anything about Laplace to be able to use and understand annihilators. In fact, in the book I mentioned at the end, Laplace doesn't come up until Chapter 7. (The next chapter.) Also, you should know how to find the undetermined coefficients, anyway. That's taught still earlier. And I show how to do that here.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the particular soluton that you propose:

> $$v_p(t) = \small At\sin(t) + Bt \sin(t) + C \sin(t) + D \cos(t)$$

should be:$$v_p(t) = \small At\sin(t) + Bt \cos(t) + C \sin(t) + D \cos(t)$$

The particular solution will be an amplified and phase shifted version of the input (linearity), so a good guess would be:$$v_p(t)=Kt\sin\left(t+\varphi\right)$$

1. The product rule of the derivative will produce:$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[t\sin\left(t+\varphi\right)\right]=\sin\left(t+\varphi\right)+t\cos\left(t+\varphi\right)$$

The differential equation becomes:
$$2K\sin\left(t+\varphi\right)+2Kt\cos\left(t+\varphi\right)+Kt\sin\left(t+\varphi\right)=5t\sin\left( t\right)$$

2. Applying the trigonometric identities:
   $$\cos\left(a+b\right)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
   $$\sin\left(a+b\right)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$

Then collecting the appropriate terms the coefficients A,B,C,D can be identified allowing \$K\$ and \$\varphi\$ to be found.